# Настройка правильной перспективы для дочерних элементов на трехмерной плоскости в CSS

Tags: html, css, css3, html5, svg

У меня есть шестигранная решетка `SVG`, наклоненная под углом `45` градусов.

На отдельных шестиугольниках, где есть красные прямоугольниками, я хотел бы разместить изображения  которые, должны  стоять вертикально относительно плоскости сетки.

Изображения / прямоугольники не обязательно должны иметь полные 90 градусов, но мне сложнее всего заставить их иметь любую перспективу, даже немного отличающуюся от плоскости.

Есть ли способ отменить перспективу для дочерних элементов или переработать `CSS-transforms` так, чтобы это выглядело правильно?

```css
.display {
    animation: displayFlicker 100ms cubic-bezier(.37, 0, .41, 1.74) 100ms 1 normal forwards;
    -webkit-animation: displayFlicker 100ms cubic-bezier(.37, 0, .41, 1.74) 100ms 1 normal forwards;
    background: #000;
    display: block;
    border-left: 0.25rem solid #000;
    border-right: 0.25rem solid #000;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    height: 480px;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 1096px;
}
#hexGrid {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;    
    display: block;
    height: 100%;
    -webkit-transform: perspective(44vw) rotateX(45deg) scale3d(1.6, 1.6, 1.6); 
    -moz-transform: perspective(44vw) rotateX(45deg) scale3d(1.6, 1.6, 1.6);    
    -ms-transform: perspective(44vw) rotateX(45deg) scale3d(1.6, 1.6, 1.6); 
    -o-transform: perspective(44vw) rotateX(45deg) scale3d(1.6, 1.6, 1.6);  
    transform: perspective(44vw) rotateX(45deg) scale3d(1.6, 1.6, 1.6);
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
    width: 100%;
}
.hexContainer {
    outline: none;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
}
.hex {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 4.4vmin;
    opacity: 1;
    outline: none;
    position: relative;
    stroke: #0CF;
    stroke-width: 0.0625rem;
    transform: scale3d(1, 1, 1);
    transition: all linear 300ms;
    width: 8vmin;
}
.hex.open {
    fill: rgba(0, 204, 255, 0.3);
}
.hex.blocked {
    fill: url(#blockedHexPattern);
    fill-opacity: 0.3;
}
.hexContainer:focus .open, .hexContainer:hover .open {
    cursor: pointer;
    fill: rgba(0, 204, 255, 0.8);
    outline: none;
}
.hexContainer:focus .blocked, .hexContainer:hover .blocked {
    cursor: pointer;
    fill: url(#blockedHexPattern);
    fill-opacity: 1;
    outline: none;
}
.hexContainer:focus .occupied, .hexContainer:hover .occupied {
    cursor: pointer;
    fill: rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.8);
    outline: none;
}
.hexContainer:focus .open, .hexContainer:focus .open.unblock {
    transform-origin: 50% 0%;
}
.hexContainer:focus .blocked {
    opacity: 1; 
    transform-origin: 50% 0%;
}
.hexContainer.active .open {
    fill: rgba(0, 204, 255, 0.8);
    opacity: 1; 
}
#blockedHexPattern line {
    stroke: #0CF;
    stroke-width: 0.0625rem;
}
#hexGrid .rect {
    transform: rotateX(0deg);   
}
```

```html
<div id="stationMap" class="display">
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="55 -30 360 360" id="hexGrid">
    <defs>
        <pattern x="0" y="0" height="10" width="10" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" id="blockedHexPattern">
            <line x1="0" y1="10" x2="10" y2="0"></line>
        </pattern>
    </defs>
    <a id="hex0-0" class="hexContainer">
        <polygon class="hex open" points="81.96152422706632,45 55.98076211353316,60 30,45 30.000000000000004,14.999999999999996 55.98076211353315,0 81.96152422706632,14.999999999999986"></polygon>
    </a>
    <a id="hex0-2" class="hexContainer">
        <polygon class="hex blocked" points="185.88457268119896,45 159.9038105676658,60 133.92304845413264,45 133.92304845413264,14.999999999999996 159.9038105676658,0 185.88457268119896,14.999999999999986" fill="url(#blockedHexPattern)"></polygon>
    </a>
    <a id="hex0-6" class="hexContainer">
        <polygon class="hex blocked" points="393.7306695894642,45 367.749907475931,60 341.76914536239786,45 341.76914536239786,14.999999999999996 367.749907475931,0 393.7306695894642,14.999999999999986" fill="url(#blockedHexPattern)"></polygon>
    </a>
    <a id="hex0-7" class="hexContainer">
        <polygon class="hex blocked" points="445.6921938165305,45 419.71143170299734,60 393.7306695894642,45 393.7306695894642,14.999999999999996 419.71143170299734,0 445.6921938165305,14.999999999999986" fill="url(#blockedHexPattern)"></polygon>
    </a>
    <a id="hex1-0" class="hexContainer">
        <polygon class="hex open" points="55.98076211353316,90 30.000000000000004,105 4.01923788646684,90 4.019237886466843,60 29.999999999999993,45 55.98076211353315,59.999999999999986"></polygon>
        <rect class="rect" fill="red" x="5" y="67.5" width="50" height="40"/>
    </a>
    <a id="hex1-3" class="hexContainer">
        <polygon class="hex blocked" points="211.8653347947321,90 185.88457268119893,105 159.90381056766577,90 159.90381056766577,60 185.88457268119893,45 211.8653347947321,59.999999999999986" fill="url(#blockedHexPattern)"></polygon>
    </a>
    <a id="hex1-4" class="hexContainer">
        <polygon class="hex open" points="263.82685902179844,90 237.84609690826525,105 211.8653347947321,90 211.8653347947321,60 237.84609690826525,45 263.8268590217984,59.999999999999986"></polygon>
    </a>
    <a id="hex1-5" class="hexContainer">
        <polygon class="hex open" points="315.7883832488647,90 289.80762113533154,105 263.8268590217984,90 263.8268590217984,60 289.80762113533154,45 315.7883832488647,59.999999999999986"></polygon>
    </a>
    <a id="hex1-6" class="hexContainer">
        <polygon class="hex open" points="367.749907475931,90 341.76914536239786,105 315.7883832488647,90 315.7883832488647,60 341.76914536239786,45 367.749907475931,59.999999999999986"></polygon>
    </a>
    <a id="hex1-7" class="hexContainer">
        <polygon class="hex open" points="419.71143170299734,90 393.7306695894642,105 367.749907475931,90 367.749907475931,60 393.7306695894642,45 419.71143170299734,59.999999999999986"></polygon>
        <rect class="rect" fill="red" x="369" y="67.5" width="50" height="40"/>
    </a>
    <a id="hex2-0" class="hexContainer">
        <polygon class="hex open" points="81.96152422706632,134.99999999999997 55.98076211353316,150 30,134.99999999999997 30.000000000000004,104.99999999999999 55.98076211353315,89.99999999999999 81.96152422706632,104.99999999999997"></polygon>
    </a>
    <a id="hex2-2" class="hexContainer">
        <polygon class="hex blocked" points="185.88457268119896,134.99999999999997 159.9038105676658,150 133.92304845413264,134.99999999999997 133.92304845413264,104.99999999999999 159.9038105676658,89.99999999999999 185.88457268119896,104.99999999999997" fill="url(#blockedHexPattern)"></polygon>
    </a>
    <a id="hex2-3" class="hexContainer">
        <polygon class="hex open" points="237.84609690826525,134.99999999999997 211.8653347947321,150 185.88457268119893,134.99999999999997 185.88457268119893,104.99999999999999 211.8653347947321,89.99999999999999 237.84609690826525,104.99999999999997"></polygon>
    </a>
    <a id="hex2-4" class="hexContainer">
        <polygon class="hex open" points="289.80762113533154,134.99999999999997 263.8268590217984,150 237.84609690826522,134.99999999999997 237.84609690826522,104.99999999999999 263.8268590217984,89.99999999999999 289.80762113533154,104.99999999999997"></polygon>
    </a>
    <a id="hex2-5" class="hexContainer">
        <polygon class="hex open" points="341.76914536239786,134.99999999999997 315.7883832488647,150 289.80762113533154,134.99999999999997 289.80762113533154,104.99999999999999 315.7883832488647,89.99999999999999 341.76914536239786,104.99999999999997"></polygon>
    </a>
    <a id="hex2-6" class="hexContainer">
        <polygon class="hex open" points="393.7306695894642,134.99999999999997 367.749907475931,150 341.76914536239786,134.99999999999997 341.76914536239786,104.99999999999999 367.749907475931,89.99999999999999 393.7306695894642,104.99999999999997"></polygon>
    </a>
    <a id="hex2-7" class="hexContainer">
        <polygon class="hex open" points="445.6921938165305,134.99999999999997 419.71143170299734,150 393.7306695894642,134.99999999999997 393.7306695894642,104.99999999999999 419.71143170299734,89.99999999999999 445.6921938165305,104.99999999999997"></polygon>
    </a>
    <a id="hex3-0" class="hexContainer">
        <polygon class="hex open" points="55.98076211353316,179.99999999999997 30.000000000000004,194.99999999999997 4.01923788646684,179.99999999999997 4.019237886466843,149.99999999999997 29.999999999999993,134.99999999999997 55.98076211353315,149.99999999999994"></polygon>
    </a>
    <a id="hex3-3" class="hexContainer">
        <polygon class="hex blocked" points="211.8653347947321,179.99999999999997 185.88457268119893,194.99999999999997 159.90381056766577,179.99999999999997 159.90381056766577,149.99999999999997 185.88457268119893,134.99999999999997 211.8653347947321,149.99999999999994" fill="url(#blockedHexPattern)"></polygon>
    </a>
    <a id="hex3-5" class="hexContainer">
        <polygon class="hex blocked" points="315.7883832488647,179.99999999999997 289.80762113533154,194.99999999999997 263.8268590217984,179.99999999999997 263.8268590217984,149.99999999999997 289.80762113533154,134.99999999999997 315.7883832488647,149.99999999999994" fill="url(#blockedHexPattern)"></polygon>
    </a>
    <a id="hex3-7" class="hexContainer">
        <polygon class="hex blocked" points="419.71143170299734,179.99999999999997 393.7306695894642,194.99999999999997 367.749907475931,179.99999999999997 367.749907475931,149.99999999999997 393.7306695894642,134.99999999999997 419.71143170299734,149.99999999999994" fill="url(#blockedHexPattern)"></polygon>
    </a>
    <a id="hex4-0" class="hexContainer">
        <polygon class="hex open" points="81.96152422706632,224.99999999999997 55.98076211353316,239.99999999999997 30,224.99999999999997 30.000000000000004,194.99999999999997 55.98076211353315,179.99999999999997 81.96152422706632,194.99999999999994"></polygon>
    </a>
    <a id="hex4-1" class="hexContainer">
        <polygon class="hex blocked" points="133.92304845413264,224.99999999999997 107.94228634059948,239.99999999999997 81.96152422706632,224.99999999999997 81.96152422706632,194.99999999999997 107.94228634059948,179.99999999999997 133.92304845413264,194.99999999999994" fill="url(#blockedHexPattern)"></polygon>
    </a>
    <a id="hex4-2" class="hexContainer">
        <polygon class="hex blocked" points="185.88457268119896,224.99999999999997 159.9038105676658,239.99999999999997 133.92304845413264,224.99999999999997 133.92304845413264,194.99999999999997 159.9038105676658,179.99999999999997 185.88457268119896,194.99999999999994" fill="url(#blockedHexPattern)"></polygon>
    </a>
    <a id="hex4-3" class="hexContainer">
        <polygon class="hex blocked" points="237.84609690826525,224.99999999999997 211.8653347947321,239.99999999999997 185.88457268119893,224.99999999999997 185.88457268119893,194.99999999999997 211.8653347947321,179.99999999999997 237.84609690826525,194.99999999999994" fill="url(#blockedHexPattern)"></polygon>
    </a>
    <a id="hex4-4" class="hexContainer">
        <polygon class="hex open" points="289.80762113533154,224.99999999999997 263.8268590217984,239.99999999999997 237.84609690826522,224.99999999999997 237.84609690826522,194.99999999999997 263.8268590217984,179.99999999999997 289.80762113533154,194.99999999999994"></polygon>
    </a>
    <a id="hex4-5" class="hexContainer">
        <polygon class="hex open" points="341.76914536239786,224.99999999999997 315.7883832488647,239.99999999999997 289.80762113533154,224.99999999999997 289.80762113533154,194.99999999999997 315.7883832488647,179.99999999999997 341.76914536239786,194.99999999999994"></polygon>
    </a>
    <a id="hex4-6" class="hexContainer">
        <polygon class="hex open" points="393.7306695894642,224.99999999999997 367.749907475931,239.99999999999997 341.76914536239786,224.99999999999997 341.76914536239786,194.99999999999997 367.749907475931,179.99999999999997 393.7306695894642,194.99999999999994"></polygon>
    </a>
</svg>
</div>
```

<sub>Свободный перевод вопроса [Setting proper perspective for child elements on a 3d plane in CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33213115/7394871) от участника  [@VirtuosiMedia](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13281/virtuosimedia).</sub>

Comment: ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/q/33213115/7394871

Answer (score 2):

Поскольку трехмерные преобразования не могут быть обработаны должным образом для элементов SVG, я бы предложил другой подход для сетки шестиугольников. Это может быть достигнуто с помощью простого HTML и CSS, как показано в этом вопросе  [Responsive grid of hexagons.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26114920/18119921)

Это позволяет делать `3d-transforms` на дочерних элементах с [transform-style](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-style) [свойствами](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-style)

Адаптированный к вашему варианту  CSS,  может выглядеть так:

[Демо:](http://codepen.io/web-tiki/pen/WQMyyZ)

```css
body{
  background:rgb(123, 158, 158);
  perspective:500px;
}
#categories{
  width:70%;
  margin:0 auto;
  transform:rotateX(45deg);
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
}
#categories:after{
  content:"";
  display:block;
  clear:both;
}
#categories li{
  position:relative;
  list-style-type:none;
  width:17.364%; /* = (100-4.5) / 5.5 */
  padding-bottom: 20.05%; /* =  width /0.866 */
  float:left;
  overflow:hidden;
  visibility:hidden;  
  transform: rotate(-60deg) skewY(30deg);
}

#categories li:nth-child(10n+6), #categories li:nth-child(10n+7), #categories li:nth-child(10n+8), #categories li:nth-child(10n+9), #categories li:nth-child(10n+10) {
    margin-top: -4.2%;
    margin-bottom: -4.2%;
    transform: translateX(50%) rotate(-60deg) skewY(30deg);
  }
#categories li:nth-child(10n+6){
    margin-left:0.5%;
  }
  #categories li:nth-child(5n+2) {
    margin-left:1%;
    margin-right:1%;
  }
  #categories li:nth-child(5n+3),#categories li:nth-child(5n+4){
    margin-right:1%;
  }

#categories li div{
  position:absolute;
  visibility:visible;
  width:100%; height:100%;
  text-align:center;
  color:#fff;
  overflow:hidden;  
  transform: skewY(-30deg) rotate(60deg);
  background-color:rgba(0,0,0,.2);
  transition:background-color .3s;
  border-left:2px solid #000;  
  border-right:2px solid #000;
  box-sizing:border-box;
  -webkit-backface-visibility:hidden;
}
#categories li div:hover, #categories .up:hover span:after{
  background-color:rgba(0,0,0,.5);
}
#categories li div:before, #categories li div:after{
  content:'';
  position:absolute;
  width:100%;height:49.6%;
  left:-2px;top:25.5%;
  
  border-left:2px solid #000;
  border-right:2px solid #000;
  transform:rotate(60deg);
  visibility:visible;
}
#categories li div:before{
    transform:rotate(-60deg);
}

#categories li img{
  display:block;
  left:-100%; right:-100%;
  width: auto; height:100%;
  margin:0 auto;
  visibility:visible;
}
#categories .up, #categories .up div{
  transform-style:preserve-3d;
  overflow:visible;
  visibility:hidden;
  background-color:transparent;
}
#categories .up span{
  display:block;
  width:100%;height:100%;
  position:absolute;
  top:0; left:0;
  overflow:hidden;
}
#categories .up span:after{
  content:'';
  position:absolute;
  left:0;top:0;
  width:100%;height:100%;
  border-left:2px solid #000;
  border-right:2px solid #000;
  box-sizing:border-box;
  background-color:rgba(0,0,0,.2);
  transform: skewY(-30deg) rotate(60deg);
  transition:background-color .3s;
  visibility:visible;
}

#categories .up img{
  width:100%; height:auto;
  position:absolute;
  transform-origin: 50% 100%;
  transform: rotateX(-45deg);
  z-index:1;
}
```

```html
<ul id="categories" class="clr">
   <li><div></div></li>
  <li class="up"><span></span><div><img src="https://farm9.staticflickr.com/8461/8048823381_0fbc2d8efb.jpg" alt=""/></div></li>
  <li><div></div></li>  
  <li><div></div></li>
  <li class="up"><span></span><div><img src="https://farm7.staticflickr.com/6217/6216951796_e50778255c.jpg" alt=""/></div></li>
  <li class="pusher"></li>
  <li class="pusher"></li>
  <li class="pusher"></li>
  <li><div></div></li>
  <li class="pusher"></li>
  <li><div></div></li>
  <li><div></div></li>
  <li><div></div></li>
  <li class="pusher"></li>
  <li><div></div></li>
  <li class="up"><span></span><div><img src="https://farm5.staticflickr.com/4144/5053682635_b348b24698.jpg" alt=""/></div></li>
  <li class="pusher"></li>
  <li><div></div></li>
  <li><div></div></li>
</ul>
```

Эта сетка шестиугольников может быть адаптирована для нескольких вариантов использования (количество шестиугольников в ряду, выравнивание шестиугольников ...)

<sub>Свободный перевод ответа [Setting proper perspective for child elements on a 3d plane in CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33302054/7394871) от участника  [@web-tiki](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1811992/web-tiki).</sub>

Comment: Салам Саша. Я хотел спросить достойно ли я сделал? Что бы не стрёмно было показать этот пример : https://codepen.io/topicstarter/pen/mYdKzG  а сам вопрос был вот здесь : https://otvet.mail.ru/question/214466518

Comment: @MaximLensky Хорошо сделал, смотрится очень интересно. Сделал сложнее, чем требовалось в вопросе. Там у них только простая анимация вращения вокруг нижней точки.  У тебя можно ещё устранить подергивание анимации в конце трансформации листочков. Для этого надо сделать:  начальный путь - конечный путь - начальный путь

Comment: Вроде бы переделал , так лучше ?

Comment: @MaximLensky намного лучше стало, но рывки в конце анимации остались. В принципе можно оставить как есть. Если есть желание, то можно попытаться убрать рывки, хотя бы на среднем листочке, где особенно видно.

Comment: Пускай дёргается  ... мне не мешает это ..

Comment: И кстати не чайно исправил эту дёргалку ..поглянь

Comment: @MaximLensky вижу, что убрал лишние проценты 50% 70% 90% в `keyFrames a3` и углы в `transform: rotate(-7deg)` поменял местами :)